# How do I include a Capybara::Node::Element in its own invocation of one of the Matchers methods?

Tags: capybara

Given that I have a [Capybara node element](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element) foo.

How do I get instance methods from the [Matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers) module to include the node itself.

So if I run

```
nodeFoo.has_css?("a");
```

I want it to return true if nodeFoo is an anchor element with no children. Currently it seems like Capybara only searches the children of a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara API doesn't provide a direct way to do so. All Capybara::Node::Finders work this way.

If you want to check which tag name `nodeFoo` has you can use [`tag_name` function](http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#tag_name-instance_method):

```
nodeFoo.tag_name
```

So you can do what you want with:

```
nodeFoo.tag_name == 'a' || nodeFoo.has_css?('a')
```

Comment: Sorry I gave a specific example, but I was curious about the more general case.

Comment: @Jazzepi in general case it's not possible. `find_element` works as it works - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/element/:id/element, http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method